# Postgresql update

Tags: sql, postgresql, sql-update, jsonb

I am new to postgreql and sql itself.So
how do I set a json value of 'class'? Official documentation and other resources provided me with the function jsonb_set which i used to set a hard coded value of '"X"', however I am not able to set a dynamic value based off of the student table's column.

```
update dp_user_custom_properties_v2 ducpv
    set json_value = jsonb_set(ducpv.json_value, '{class}',s.class::text)
    from students s
    where s.user_id = ducpv.user_id and s.status is null;
```

this doesn't work but

```
set json_value = jsonb_set(ducpv.json_value, '{class}','"A"')
```

this does.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is happening because 3rd argument of `jsonb_set()` should be a jsonb and you are passing text. You should convert it to jsonb first.
Use `to_jsonb()` like below.

```
update dp_user_custom_properties_v2 ducpv
    set json_value = jsonb_set(ducpv.json_value, '{class}',to_jsonb(s.class::text))
    from students s
    where s.user_id = ducpv.user_id and s.status is null;
```

Comment: Yep it works as expected .I actually found another way of doing it .But thanks for answering.

Comment: Why can i not just cast it like `s.class:jsonb`?

Comment: You don't actually need the cast to `text`, It should be enough to use `to_jsonb(s.class)`

Answer (score 0):

I found another way of doing it looking thorugh online resources -

```
update dp_user_custom_properties_v2 ducpv
                        set json_value = ducpv.json_value||jsonb_build_object('section', s.section,'class', s.class)
                        from students s
                        where s.user_id = ducpv.user_id and s.status is null;
```